pdfApi.UploadFile doesn’t works
pdfApi.UploadFile doesn’t works as it is throwing an exception always as “{“Error calling UploadFile: { ““error””: { ““code””: ““resourceNotFound””, ““message””: ““Invalid URL. Please check for correct usage of the domain and version.””, ““description””: ““Operation Failed. Invalid URL.””, }}”}”
Please let me know what I am missing here
Please find my code here
Using file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(sourcePath)
Dim response = pdfApi.UploadFile(“resultFiles.pdf”, file)
End Using

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please, check the latest version (24.4.1) of Aspose.Pdf-Cloud
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Pdf-Cloud/).
